# What are the benefits and the drawbacks of the Sicilian defense

Tags: analysis, strategy, theory

I am learning to play chess, and I am focusing my attention on the Sicilian defense. Many people says is one of the best openings against e4 when playing with black, and I think also it is a good opening. But sometimes, if I play it, I get weak in the queen side, and so I vulnerable to attacks there.

So I was wondering which are the benefits and the drawbacks of the Siciclian defense.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You may want to consider factors other than the chess game.  I once sat down to play chess with someone I hadn't played before and they played 1. e4.  I responded ..c5 and they said "You look like a Sicilian player"  I asked, "What to you mean?"  He said, "Gaunt, wiry, desperate."

Answer (score 2):

The Sicilian defense is a very strong opening that gives very complicated and rich positions. Before I talk about the drawbacks and the advantages I want to point out that if by attack you mean attack on your king then I must say that you should never castle queenside when playing the Sicilian defense. However, I think that you mean that white exerts pressure on you Queenside. I would recommend that you push b5 early on and fianchetto the bishop on b7 such that it is defending the a6 pawn. With this, it's possible to place the rook on c8 and to put pressure on white's queenside.

Playing the Sicilian defense has a lot of possibilities and advantages, but it can be quite frustrating especially when you first start playing it and don't know much of the ideas and lines. Below I have attempted to divide categorize the advantages and disadvantages.

Advantages: 2 central pawns, Queenside pawn storm, and Strong exchange sacrifices
Disadvantages: Rapid development from white, Kingside attack from white, and passive looking setup from black

I would highly recommend getting sharper on your tactics if you are intending to play the Sicilian in your games. There are a variety of websites such as Lichess and Chess.com where you can do this. The Sicilian defense often leads to razor-sharp positions. Learn from people who play the Sicilian defense against you as well. Wish you the best of luck!